# Using to SOAP API in SpringBoot application to get the DE data

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions, soap, java

I'm new to SF Marketing Cloud and need to use Soap API in SpringBoot application to get DataExtensions data to do some manipulations. I'm not sure where to get MC DataExtensions API/end Point as well as what jar files required to add within SpringBoot Project. If any one having same example, can you please share

Answer (score 1):

Here are some links to get you going.

Get started with SOAP API
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api.htm

You'll be able to read data extensions rows using

- Method - Retrieve. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieve.htm
- Object - DataExtensionObject. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextensionobject.htm

You'll need to update the data using

- Method - Update. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/update.htm
- Object - DataExtensionObject.